# How to configure a blacklist in Squid 3?

Tags: squid

I configure squid like this, but the blacklist doesn't work. I look for something in the web, but nothing.

```
#SQUID squid.conf

http_port 8080

############################################################

#Database Authentication MYSQL

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/squid_db_auth --dsn "DBI:mysql:database=something " --user something --password something --plaintext --persist
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 30 minute
auth_param basic casesensitive off
acl db-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow db-auth

#############################################################

#ACL

acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl blacklist dstdom_regex -i "/etc/squid3/blacklist"

##############################################################


#LISTA OPERAZIONI ACL
http_access deny blacklist

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny all

##############################################################

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
```

The blacklist file is like this:

```
facebook.it
facebook.com
```

Comment: Welcome to AU?  A quick question about your output, the line " http_access deny blacklist", should that not read " http_access allow blacklist".  perhaps if you change this setting

Answer (score 1):

`http_access` statements are evaluated sequentially for each request and once matched the evaluation stops. Thus `http_access allow db-auth` should be placed **after** `http_access deny blacklist`. This way, the blacklist is enforced and then the authentication takes place.